# Application deployment with git/jenkins/angular

Tags: angularjs, git, jenkins

We have a development,uat and production environment for our angular/java/mongodb app. At the moment we are moving our deploying the same build to dev and uat. The problem with that is that some things are not finished and basically not ready to be deployed to uat. What is a good way of managing/selecting which commits/changesets are to be deployed to uat/prod? If I know which commits I want is how can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use case we have is that some builds need to be tested (by other jobs) before we know if they are good enough to deploy / release.

We use the ["Promoted Builds Plugin"](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Promoted+Builds+Plugin) for that. There is a manual promotion process as well.